# Xcode: Source control is disabled

Tags: xcode, git

Fairly straightforward question. When creating an Xcode 8 project, Xcode doesn't give me the option to create a local Git repo. The option is grayed out. Also, in existing projects, all options within the Source Control menu are grayed out. Git is installed on my computer. What's the deal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `.git` folder at the root level of your project?  From the root level, if you type `git status` from the bash what do you see?

Comment: Source control is disabled before I even create the project. The screenshot above is in the project creation process.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions.  I'm trying to determine if Git works _anywhere_ inside your project folder.  If yes, then this is an XCode problem, if not then maybe Git has a problem.

Comment: When `git status`ing in the intended root directory, I get `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`.

Comment: Bingo.  Your source project is not a Git repo.  Try creating a repo there from the command line.  I realize this is not a long term fix for XCode, but it might at least get you back to work.

Comment: I can always create a repo from Terminal, but I'm trying to access some of Xcode's git features that have been disabled for me and convince it that source control isn't disabled (see updated screenshot).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you enabled and configured it via the preferences?

[image: Xcode source control preference]

Comment: vote up for you! ,  it is my mistake, thanks you so much! sir!

Comment: That was somehow disabled automatically for me. Weird but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer, in my case I added git manually and wanted to commit from xCode but the options were disabled. Unchecking and checking enable source control option like shown above worked for me.